# pythonanwhere newbie: I don't see sqlite option

Tags: pythonanywhere

I see an option for MySql and Postgres, and have read help messages for sqlite, but I don't see anyway to use it or to install it.  So it appears that it's available or else there wouldn't be any help messages, but I can't find it.  I can't do any 'sudo', so no 'apt install', so don't know how to invoke and use it!

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is already installed. You don't need to invoke anything to install it. Just configure your web app to use it.